# python get all values from nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following dict and want to access all the id's:

```
"applicationCategories": [
        {
            "id": "test1",
            "name": "Email",
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": "aaaaaaa",
                    "name": "Gmail"
                },
                {
                    "id": "bbbbb",
                    "name": "Host-based email (POP3/IMAP/SMTP)"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "test2",
            "name": "Blogging",
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": "ccccc",
                    "name": "Blogger"
                },
                {
                    "id": "dddd",
                    "name": "WordPress"
                }
            ]
```

I want to access all the id's ... for example :

applicationCategories["id"] = gives me test1 but i want all of them ... test1 and test2

Comment: `applicationCategories["id"]` would give you a TypeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume the dictionary you provided is referenced as my_dictionary. In that case:

```
my_dictionary = {"applicationCategories": [
        {
            "id": "test1",
            "name": "Email",
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": "aaaaaaa",
                    "name": "Gmail"
                },
                {
                    "id": "bbbbb",
                    "name": "Host-based email (POP3/IMAP/SMTP)"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "test2",
            "name": "Blogging",
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": "ccccc",
                    "name": "Blogger"
                },
                {
                    "id": "dddd",
                    "name": "WordPress"
                }
            ]}]} 

for elem in my_dictionary["applicationCategories"]:
        print(elem["id"])
```

This code will print test1 and test2, therefore it allows you to access these values. Howver, your question is very vague and I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

> applicationCategories["id"] = gives me test1

It really doesn't.

Comment: Hey this worked! , thank you.. what if i wanted to access the inner dictionary inside the list applications

Comment: If you want to get all the nested ids, check the answer by @Ajax1234. In the code I provided, elem["applications"] inside the for loop will give you access to the list of inner dictionaries, so you can loop through them using the same principle (by adding another for loop of similar structure)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
d = {"applicationCategories": [
        {
            "id": "test1",
            "name": "Email",
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": "aaaaaaa",
                    "name": "Gmail"
                },
                {
                    "id": "bbbbb",
                    "name": "Host-based email (POP3/IMAP/SMTP)"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "test2",
            "name": "Blogging",
            "applications": [
                {
                    "id": "ccccc",
                    "name": "Blogger"
                },
                {
                    "id": "dddd",
                    "name": "WordPress"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

ids = [x["id"] for x in d["applicationCategories"]]
print(ids)
```

Output :

```
['test1', 'test2']
```

Or :

```
for i in d["applicationCategories"]:
    print(i["id"])
```

Output :

```
test1
test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
d = {'applicationCategories': [{'id': 'test1', 'name': 'Email', 'applications': [{'id': 'aaaaaaa', 'name': 'Gmail'}, {'id': 'bbbbb', 'name': 'Host-based email (POP3/IMAP/SMTP)'}]}, {'id': 'test2', 'name': 'Blogging', 'applications': [{'id': 'ccccc', 'name': 'Blogger'}, {'id': 'dddd', 'name': 'WordPress'}]}]}
result = [i for b in d['applicationCategories'] for i in [b['id'], *[k['id'] for k in b['applications']]]]
```

Output:

```
['test1', 'aaaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'test2', 'ccccc', 'dddd']
```

However, for structures of arbitrary depth, you can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_ids(d):
   yield from filter(None, [d.get('id')])
   for b in d.values():
     if isinstance(b, dict):
       yield from get_ids(b)
     elif isinstance(b, list):
       for j in b:
          yield from get_ids(j)

list(get_ids(struct))
```

Output:

```
['test1', 'aaaaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'test2', 'ccccc', 'dddd']
```